# Rotation and fixed points (2)

Tags: complex-analysis

The motivation to this question can be seen in

[Rotation and fixed points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263709/rotation-and-fixed-points)

My qeustion is: The vector $(u,v)$  (also $(x,y)$) depend on the variable $s$. When $\theta (s)\ne 0\,\pmod{2\pi}$  we get $(u(s),v(s))=0$  and I know that $(u(s),v(s))=0$  have infinitely many roots with respect to $s$. So what happen to the unicity of the menstioned fixed point $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the accepted answer points out, you cannot deduce uniqueness in that case. Also, maybe it is just the way you phrase it, but from what is given, you only know, in the other case, that those vectors mapping to $(0, 0)$ are fixed points; but no such vectors might exist if 0 is not in the image of $u$ (or $v$) - at least you do not mention anything about these mappings. You do not have infinitely many fixed points in this case, as you type above (not w/o further conditions than those given). If $\theta (s) = 0$ mod $2 \pi$, then not knowing about those 2 mappings does not matter as they are rotated by the identity, and so mapped to themselves, and so are (trivially) fixed points for any $s$. They will not be unique (again, as pointed out by Calvin Lin in the answer you accepted). If you worry about continuity of fixed points under parametric changes, this is an entirely different question; and in this case, the change is discontinuous at $(0, 0$.